# ZK Events Called Twice

Tags: zk

We have a Java application with ZK 5.0. Actually, we are doing a Migration to ZK 8.

We have a problem with the events, some times, they are called Twice.

For example, in this line we send an Event to the Controller from JavaScript:

```
zAu.send(new zk.Event(zk.Widget.$(this), 'onMakePackageOnWebDav', JSON.stringify(data)));
```

And, in the Controller the method onMakePackageOnWebDav is executed, and when is finished, is ejecuted again.

It's happen in other objects, for example, the ComboBox in the zul files.

```
<combobox cols="7" id="combStates"  readonly="true" tabindex="4" selectedItem="window$composer.state"/>
```

When a item is selected from this Comboox, the setter for the variable "state" is called twice, one with the value selected in the Combo and again with a null value.

Someone knows why this problem can occur?

Comment: did you try to see what requests are send to server? The events you can get out of it.

Comment: Can you reproduce the behavior on zkfiddle?

Comment: I try, but i can't load my code on zkfiddle.

Comment: My project recently went through the same 5 to 8 upgrade and noticed duplicate events. Also, one of our `ComboBox`s broke. For example, if you type a character to trigger the drop-down to open, it automatically selects the first item. No matter which option is chosen it always chooses the first, unless the window is resized sufficiently small. It appears to be window size related, or some race condition. I also noticed if I remove this call, `Events.postEvent(Events.ON_SELECT, MyComboBox.this, value);`, autocomplete works but it breaks other things.